# Juniper ztp trigger system requests

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex, automation

I have automated my network provisioning with ztp and ansible and it's already rocking.
When ztp finishes I have a working config but I'm missing 2 things:

- the xe-0/1/2 and xe-0/1/3 on my ex3300 are still configured as vc-ports
- my rescue config is not saved

Is there a way to issue requests to the system via ztp?
My approach would be to configure an [event-policy](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos14.2/topics/usage-guidelines/automation-configuring-an-event-policy-to-execute-operational-mode-commands.html) to run these commands when ztp is finished, but I fail to find a event after the ztp process has finished.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Not via ZTP, but I've just put together a couple of Ansible modules for you to handle both of these tasks here: https://github.com/dfex/dfex-ansible-modules

They're pretty self-explanatory - `junos_save_rescue` for saving the rescue configuration, and `junos_op_cli` for executing arbitrary Operational mode commands in Junos.

There is a `junos-op-cli` example in the README specifically targeting the removal of the EX3300 default vc-ports.

Feedback and improvement suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

As far a i know your not able to do that with ztp.

But why not let Ansible login and use raw commands ? or create a bash script with the expect command and let Ansible run that ?

i know both solutions are not ideal but they can get the job done.

Good luck! hope my 2 cents helps.